# AngularJS - inner directive - Order of postLink function calls change when I am replacing template property with templateUrl property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a weird situation.
If I have an outer directive that contains 2 directives

inner-directive1 - has a **template** defined.

inner-directive2 - has a **templateUrl** defined.

The inner-directive1 postLink function is being called before the outer-directive postLink function - as expected.

But, the inner-directive2 poslink function is being called after the outer-directive postLink - NOT as expected.

The calls to the postLink function are : *inner-directive1, outer-directive, inner-directive2* and I was expecting : *inner-directive1, inner-directive2, outer-directive*.

The template for the outer directive is:

```
<div ng-transclude><div inner1></div><div inner2></div></div>
```

please look at the JsFiddle

Does anyone know the reason why?
And is there a way I can make it work as it is expected ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benland/cPJC2/1/) - Please look at the console log.
Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Can you share the code for the directives?

Comment: @mortalapeman just edited the question and added a JsFiddle.

Answer (score 10):

Here's why, from the Angular directive docs(http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> templateUrl - Same as template but the template is loaded from the specified URL. Because the template loading is asynchronous, **the compilation/linking is suspended until the template is loaded.**

So that particular directive stops linking until your template is loaded.  During that time your other directives jump in and run.

If the timing of you link function is critical, you'll need to include the template directly instead of as a templateUrl.  Unless someone can come up with a cool way around this.

Comment: This is the answer. I just finished looking through the angular source to see if I could get my head wrapped around exactly why it was done this way, and this answer is probably the best you'll get from someone who hasn't actually worked on the source code. That compile service is some heavy stuff.

Comment: My guess as to why is that they were trapped- you can't link until you have a DOM for this element and you don't want to stall everything waiting for a load that could take a long time.  And they often suggest that people should write code that doesn't depend on the timing of link calls.  So this was their best option amongst various not-great options.  But that's me just guessing.  And yea, intense code indeed.

Comment: I prefer finding a solution other then taking the template directly inside the JavaScript because this is a good solution only when both the outer and inner extensions are mine.

Comment: @Ben Landiado if you have directives that depend on each other, you can't count on the order of execution. You will need to change your design to work within the constrains of the framework. If you update your post with more details about what you are really trying accomplish, we can probably help you redesign your directives.

Comment: Hmm, clear explanation. Is there a way around this ? so, basically ignoring the advice *not* to wait for async templates to be loaded and linked, because, well, theoretically it could just be a `<p>{{ohai}}</p>` template but you absolutely need to wait for it to be linked?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the exact use-case, but I ran into this issue when trying to use element[0].querySelector('#dynamicId');

This would result in "null" in this case since the link function was being executed from input 1 after outer link.

The fix was rather simple, in the outer directive's link function, wrap the code using element.ready():

```
element.ready(function(){
     var item = element[0].querySelector('#dynamicId');
     item.bind('blur', function(){
         alert('blur')
     });
})
```

This allows me to find the dynamic element and attach any events even if it's being async loaded from the template url.