# AngularJS Inner directive (post) link function called after outer directive's

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand that the way linking is supposed to work in directives is that post link functions are called in reverse order.  That is, inner most elements' directives' post link functions are called before outer elements'.  There's a bunch of plunkers demonstrating this behaviour online.

That said, I don't understand the behaviour I'm seeing in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mexPhjKVtWvEijFbwhql?p=preview).  The outer link function is the one being called first.  The behaviour changes if I don't use a `templateURl` in the inner directive, which makes things even weirder!

Can someone explain this?

### Edit

I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470661/angularjs-inner-directive-order-of-postlink-function-calls-change-when-i-am?rq=1) that asks the same question.  From the answer (which is from the docs):

> templateUrl - Same as template but the template is loaded from the specified URL. Because the template loading is asynchronous, the compilation/linking is suspended until the template is loaded.

A commenter in the thread added:

> if you have directives that depend on each other, you can't count on the order of execution. You will need to change your design to work within the constrains of the framework. If you update your post with more details about what you are really trying accomplish, we can probably help you redesign your directives.

So, here it goes.

### My specific case

I'm trying to write reusable form components for my app.  It uses Semantic UI, so each input field has some boilerplate elements for styling, especially dropdown selections.  This is my dropdown template to illustrate why I would rather write a custom element directive:

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="label">{{label}}</label>
    <div class="input">
        <div class="ui selection fluid dropdown">
            <i class="ui dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="default text">{{default}}</div>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in collection" data-value="{{item[value]}}">
                {{item[identifier]}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <input name="{{name}}" type="hidden"  ng-required='{{required}}'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That way I can write something slightly less verbose. And that's all fine and dandy. *However*, in some if not all my forms I would like to add validation on blur, so I wrote a directive for forms that looks for all input fields, adds a callback on change, and adds an error class if not valid.  This won't work because at linking time of the form directive *there are no input fields* because the inner directives haven't compiled and linked yet.

The end html would look something like this:

```
<form error-directive>
    <choice name="myInput" label="MyLabel" default="Select an Item" collection="data" value="id" identifier="text" ng-model="myModel" required="true"></choice>
</form>
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

> However, in some if not all my forms I would like to add validation on blur, **so I wrote a directive for forms that looks for all input fields, adds a callback on change, and adds an error class if not valid.** This won't work because at linking time of the form directive there are no input fields because the inner directives haven't compiled and linked yet.

The part in bold is supported AngularJS, you don't need a custom solution.

> Is there a better approach?

Yes: [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) and [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

If, for some other reason, you need to have a collection of all inputs in a form, [create child directives on your inputs that register themselves with a parent directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate). Don't do post-processing on child elements outside the AngularJS system using the DOM; you will end up with fragile code.